# Method to remove empty rows from DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I parsed through an Excel spreadsheet and returned the entire result as a DataTable.  However, this Excel spreadsheet has several empty rows that I would like to eliminate from the resulting DataTable.  In particular, each empty row begins with an empty cell.  So, I know that the entire row is empty if the value of the cell at the first index is empty.  Note that I cannot simply modify the Excel spreadsheet because I have to work with exactly what the client has sent to me.  Based on this information, I assumed that I could perform the following function to remove empty rows:

```
' DataTable dt has already been populated with the data

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If dt.Rows.Item(0).ToString = "" Then
        dt.Rows.Remove(row)
    ElseIf dt.Rows.Item(0) Is Nothing Then
        dt.Rows.Remove(row)
    End If
Next
```

However, after crafting this solution, I am greeted with the following error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
```

I now realize that I cannot alter the collection as I access it.  How can I get around this?  I'm wondering if I should create a new DataTable with the rows that aren't empty.  Is this the best approach or are there better options?

EDIT:  I have also tried iterating over the rows backwards:

```
For i = dt.Rows.Count() - 1 To 0
    If dt.Rows.Item(i).Item(0).ToString = "" Then
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your `For` loop is missing a `Step -1` to iterate backwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify the collection while you're enumerating it with `For Each`, but a simple `For` loop will work. You'll need to loop backwards to avoid skipping the row after a removed row.

You've also got your tests the wrong way round; if `Item(0)` returns `Nothing`, then `Item(0).ToString` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

I'm assuming the `dt.Rows.Item(0)` is a typo, and should read `row.Item(0)` instead.

```
For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
    If row.Item(0) Is Nothing Then
       dt.Rows.Remove(row)
    ElseIf row.Item(0).ToString = "" Then
       dt.Rows.Remove(row)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.Net using linq

```
 Dtset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Where(Function(row) row.ItemArray.All(Function(field) field Is Nothing Or field Is DBNull.Value Or field.Equals(""))).ToList().ForEach(Sub(row) row.Delete())
        Dtset.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
```